# How to get all the tweets in twitter wrapper object without getting index out of range error in python?

Tags: python, twitter

The object data contains all the tweets. When I give the limit as some arbitrary integer (here 200) I get index out of range error.But all the tweets are printed.When I replace 200 with len(data) only 2 or 3 tweets are printed.how can I rectify this?

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth("", "","", ""))
t.statuses.home_timeline()
data = t.search.tweets(q=query)

for i in range (0,200):    
 test = data['statuses'][i]['text']
 print test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the length of the `data['statuses']` like this

```
for i in range (len(data['statuses'])):
```